# Mongoose select on sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Schema:

```
UserSchema = new db.Schema({
   fullname : String,
   sale : [{ _id: [db.Schema.Types.ObjectId] }],
   friends : [db.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
}
```

how can I fix this code to make it select the _id field of Sale? TIA

```
user.Model
        .find({
            _id : {
                $in: friends
            }
        })
        .select('sale._id') // invalid syntax
        .exec(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserSchema = new db.Schema({
   fullname : String,
   sale : [{ type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sale' }],
   friends : [db.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
}
user.Model
    .find({
        _id : {
            $in: friends
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

You don't need `.select` as everything in the schema will be selected by default. You may want to do `.populate('sale')` which will load a full sale instance instead of just the _id.